# very simple clarification needed about ito's lemma

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I'm looking at this example in this [lecture note](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-s096-topics-in-mathematics-with-applications-in-finance-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT18_S096F13_lecnote18.pdf) (page 3, number iv):

Let $f(t,x)=t^2+x^2$, and $X_{t}=\mu t + \sigma B_{t}$, where $B_{t}$ is the standard brownian motion. We want to compute $df(t,X_{t})$.
Using Ito's lemma, I got $(2t + 2\mu X_{t} + \sigma^2)dt + 2\sigma X_{t} dB_{t}$.

However, the answer stated in that note is $(2t + 2\mu + \sigma^2)dt + 2\sigma  dB_{t}$, which basically differs from my solution by setting $X_{t}=1$.

I wonder why do we set $X_{t}=1$? Thanks.

Comment: Your solution is fine, it must be a typo in the note. Best regards.